# Gradle 1.0.0 Project Sync Failed mavenCentral

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

Good morning,

After few hours of seek, I haven't find equivalent topic for my issue .

I have make the upgrade of my Android-Studio to 1.0.1.: after that, i have make all installation(gradle, sdk, sdk-tool) and try to import my project. An important part of the gradle configuration is automaticly make. And i have try to configure the other.

In my cmd, when i make that : C:\Users\ladmin gradle -v , my computer send that:

```
Gradle 2.2.1 
---------------------------------------
Build time : 2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC 
Build number : none
Revision: 6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a
Groovy : 2.3.6
Ant : Apache Ant "TM" version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23.2013
JVM : 1.8.0_25 "Oracle Corporation 25.25-b02"
OS : Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

My Build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavencentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavencentral()
    }
}
```

My Build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/ia92/J2SE/wmqtt.jar')
    compile files('libs/ia92/J2SE/wmqttSample.jar')
    compile files('libs/ia92/J2SE/wmqttTraceFormat.jar')
}
```

My Gradle.properties (Global)

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=172.21.31.199
systemProp.http.proxyPort=4523
systemProp.http.proxyUser=administrateur
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=**********
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

My local.properties (SDK)

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\ladmin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\android-studio\\sdk
```

My Settings.gradle

```
include ':AndroidSupTelencour2'
```

When i'm use "Sync Project With Gradle file" , gradle  response is "Gradle project sync failed. Basic fonctionality(e.g editing,debugging) will...."

```
C:\Users\ladmin\AndroidstudioProjects\Android SupTel en cour 22\build.gradle
Error:(4, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavencentral()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Android SupTel en cour 2' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

When i Click on the "Show log in Explorer"

```
2014-12-16 07:59:24,748 [56948115]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 

2014-12-16 07:59:24,750 [56948117]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 

2014-12-16 07:59:24,751 [56948118]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2014-12-16 07:59:24,754 [56948121]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\ladmin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo2422746520105845491.gradle] 
2014-12-16 07:59:25,048 [56948415]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure    (ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:186)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:361)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build     file 'C:\Users\ladmin\AndroidstudioProjects\Android SupTel en cour 22\build.gradle' line: 4
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Android SupTel en cour 22'.
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform    (DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Android SupTel en cour 22'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
... 32 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method mavencentral() for arguments [] on repository container.
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at build_cqtvref3taff8svl9c2d3m3f9$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\ladmin\AndroidstudioProjects\Android SupTel en cour 22\build.gradle:4)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:55)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.repositories(DefaultScriptHandler.java:70)
at build_cqtvref3taff8svl9c2d3m3f9$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\ladmin\AndroidstudioProjects\Android SupTel en cour 22\build.gradle:3)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.buildscript(AbstractProject.java:851)
at org.gradle.api.Project$buildscript.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.Project$buildscript.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.buildscript(ProjectScript.groovy:42)
at org.gradle.api.Script$buildscript.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at build_cqtvref3taff8svl9c2d3m3f9.run(C:\Users\ladmin\AndroidstudioProjects\Android SupTel en cour 22\build.gradle:2)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
... 43 more
2014-12-16 07:59:25,049 [56948416]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavencentral()' 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavencentral()'
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:222)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:81)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:367)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)

2014-12-16 07:59:25,049 [56948416]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2014-12-16 07:59:25,049 [56948416]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavencentral()'

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Yesterday, i have compile and launch my activity on a phone so i don't understand why today he don't want passe the compile. Yesterday, before this compile, it have make an issue with the proxy http so i have configure it on auto-detect and un-check the Offline work gradle 's check box... So i'm a little lost in this story and i don't understand what's he want from me...

Thank's to read , 
Best regard ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is `mavenCentral()` and not `mavencentral()`

Comment: Ok /sors 
Thank's ^^'

Comment: but i have really an issue i don't understand because now he tell me that :     

Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android SupTel en cour 22'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0.

     Required by:
         :Android SupTel en cour 22:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.0/gradle-1.0.0.pom'.
         > repo1.maven.org

Any idea?